# Writing a csv temporary file using tempfile

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, csv

So I'm writing a test for this class (edited to be more clear):

```
class SpreadSheet(object):
    '''awesome docstring'''
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.table = []
        self.headers = []

        with open(self.filename) as csvfile:
            filereader = reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in filereader:
                self.table.append(row)

    def create_headers(self, populations):
        ...code...

    def lookup_header(self, ltr):
        ...code...

    def write_header(self, targetfile):
        ...code...
```

that so far looks like this:

```
class TestSpreadSheet(unittest.TestCase):
    @contextmanager
    def make_fake_csv(self, data):
        self.fake_namefile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        with open(self.fake_namefile, 'w') as fake_csv:
            fake_writer = csv.writer(fake_csv)
            fake_writer.writerows(data)
        yield self.fake_namefile.name
        os.unlink(self.fake_namefile.name)

    def setUp(self):
        self.headers = []
        self.table = [
            ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8'],
            ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'],
            ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'],
            ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8']]

    def test___init__(self):
        with self.make_fake_csv(self.table) as temp_csv:
            spread_sheet = SpreadSheet(temp_csv)
            self.assertEqual(
                self.table, spread_sheet.table)

    ...tests for other functions...
```

And I get this error:

```
in make_fake_csv
with open(self.fake_namefile, 'w') as fake_csv:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

I've scoured many other topics like this that point to the use of `tempfile` to make a named object or something that can actually be called using `with open...`. And while I did actually get that to work, my issues was when I tried to use the `csv` package to format my `self.table` for me into a csv formatted raw "string" (like the raw input of a csv file in other words).

Any pointers on how I can test this differently or make the current code work? Again I'm trying to:

1. figure out how to use `csv` to do all the formatting heavy-lifting to load up a fake csv file from my `self.table` so that I don't have to make a huge string formatting expression
2. make sure that the fake file works with `with open` as used in my original class `SpreadSheet` when the test is run
3. can be used further to run the test of the other functions because they too need to instantiate `SpreadSheet` with a file in order to perform their functions.

And as a side question, is it "leaner" to make a fake "memory" file to do things like this (this is what I'm attempting above) or is is just simpler to make an actual temporary file on the disk and load it up during testing and use a `tearDown()` function to delete it?

Comment: What does `print self.fake_namefile` show?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`self.fake_namefile` in your example is an instance of `NamedTemporaryFile`.  When you do the `open()` call you need to pass a string containing the file name, not a `NamedTemporaryFile` instance.  The name of the temporary file is available in the `name` variable.

```
with open(self.fake_namefile.name, 'w') as fake_csv:
```

Here's some suggestions:

- Let your Spreadsheet class take a file-like object rather than a filename.  This makes it more generic and allows it to be used with other stream based objects.  If you had this, there'd be no need to create a fake file, you could simply construct a `StringIO` instance for testing.
- If you're set on using a `NamedTemporaryFile`, I'd suggest to use it as a context manager directly as outlined in the other answer.
- You don't have to use the `delete=True` option to `NamedTemporaryFile`.  Instead, wrap your entire test in the context manager as follows.

```
def test_stuff(self):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_csv:
        self.write_csv_test_data(temp_csv)  # Create this to write to temp_csv file object.
        temp_csv.flush()
        temp_csv.seek(0)

        spread_sheet = SpreadSheet(temp_csv.name)
        # spread_sheet = SpreadSheet(temp_csv)  Use this if Spreadsheet takes a file-like object
        ...
```

**Update:**

Here's an example using only file-like objects, there's no disk file involved.

```
class SpreadSheet(object):
    '''awesome docstring'''
    def __init__(self, fileobj):
        self.table = []
        self.headers = []

        filereader = reader(fileobj, delimiter=',')
        for row in filereader:
            self.table.append(row)
    ...
```

It could then be used like this, assuming you were reading from a disk file:

```
with open(path) as csv_file:
    spreadsheet = Spreadsheet(csv_file)
    ....
```

And during testing, you can use the StringIO module to simulate a file on disk.  The test then runs with data entirely in memory so is very fast.

```
import StringIO

class TestSpreadSheet(unittest.TestCase):
    def make_fake_csv(self, data):
        """Return a populdated fake csv file object for testing."""
        fake_csv = StringIO.StringIO()
        fake_writer = csv.writer(fake_csv)
        fake_writer.writerows(data)
        fake_csv.seek(0)
        return fake_csv
    ....

    def test___init__(self):
        temp_csv = self.make_fake_csv(self.table)
        spread_sheet = SpreadSheet(temp_csv)
        self.assertEqual(
            self.table, spread_sheet.table)
```

Comment: this was excellent, thanks. To understand your first recommendation, is `open(self.filename)` the process of creating a file-like object from a string containing the file name? Hence why you can do `with file-like-object as whatever:` So do I just make that it's own line like `file_object = open(self.filename)` then do my normal `with file_object as csvfile:`?

Comment: @brianclements I've updated my answer, hopefully that answers some of your questions.

Comment: ahh I see. Thank you very much. By bringing the `open(file)` function outside of the class entirely, you therefor make the class more modular and reusable by design, which is why it's easier to not only test it using `StringIO`, but also use it in other modules as well.

Comment: I made a couple of edits for typos and to fill out the `make_fake_csv()` a little more to make it more robust for reuse. Check out the edits for details.

Answer (score 2):

`NamedTemporaryFile` returns an already opened file-like object that can be used in a `with` statement as is, no need to call `open`:

```
    self.fake_namefile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    with self.fake_namefile as fake_csv:
```

Comment: This was what I needed for my quick fix. Thanks!